# Advanced php formatting need help understand layout

Tags: php, deobfuscation

Here is the function:

```
function simplePresent($e) {

    $w = ($f = preg_match)('/ey|se|d |[sI]$|We/', $a = $e[0]);

    be == ($b = $e[1])
    ?
    $b = $w ? $a == I ? am : are : is
    :
    $w ?: $b = $b == have ? has : $b .= $f('/[h-z]$/', $b) ? es : s;

    return "$a $b $e[2]";
}
```

this is a solution on codefights. it handles formatting under defined parameters. I am trying to understand the function assignment to the variables `$f` and `$w`. Also the the use of variables with no quotes. lastly the nested question marks and colons. How is this functioning?

Thanks

Comment: As you may be aware, this is purposely obtuse code and no reasonable person would write code like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `preg_match()` is being assigned to the variable `$f` and reused later in the code. `$w` is simply the result of `preg_match()`. For example:

```
<?php
$w = ($f = 'sprintf')("foo");
// same as this:
$f = 'sprintf';
$w = $f("foo");
// which is the same as this:
$w = sprintf('foo');
```

The unquoted values will first be interpreted as constants, and the undefined constants will be interpreted as strings. Here's how a proper constant definition looks:

```
<?php
define("foo", "bar");
echo foo;
echo bar;
// PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant bar - assumed 'bar'

// same as this:
echo "bar";
echo "bar";
```

The question marks and colons are part of a [ternary statement](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary). This is a useful shorthand, but PHP recommends against stacking them together as is done there (the result is "non-obvious.") A simple one looks like this:

```
<?php
echo ($foo == "foo" ? "equal" : "inequal");
$a = $b ? $c : $d;

// this is the same as:
if ($foo == "foo") {
    echo "equal";
} else {
    echo "inequal";
}
if ($b) {
    $a = $c;
} else {
    $a = $d;
}
```